# iOS won't respect Supported Interface Orientations

Tags: ios

Frustrating. I've tried to make an app Portrait only.

In Targets => Summary => Supported Interface Options, only portrait is selected.

I've put the following on the navigation controller of my app:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
```

And even copied the same onto the root view controller of the navigation controller. It's still being presented that the view is allowed to be rotated. I'm still able to rotate my app to landscape on the iPad, and possibly even upside down on the iPhone.

Thanks!

Comment: And where is the error? The view does roatte to landscape?

Comment: Yep. Edited question to make it more clear that the view still rotates to landscape and does not respect the Supported Interface Options on the Target nor on the controller/view.

Comment: Is this the *root* view controller? In iOS 6 sub-controllers do not get a vote.

Comment: That worked. Any idea why it wasn't working with putting it in the target summary? Go ahead and answer the question so I can accept yours!